# using #pragma omp parallel for make the program slower

Tags: c++, openmp

My C++ program takes about 300 s to run.
Inside my program I need to cwis divide my vectors. VS analyzer tells this takes about 15% of running time. here is the code:

```
template <class T> myVector<T> cWisDivide(myVector<T> &vec1, 

myVector<T> &vec2)
{
    try
    {
        if (vec1._rows == vec2._rows)
        {
            myVector<T> result(vec1._rows);
            //#pragma omp parallel for 
            for (int r = 1; r <= vec1._rows; r++)
            {
                if (vec2(r) != 0)
                {
                    result(r) = vec1(r) / vec2(r);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("");
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (const exception &e)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

this function is called many time.
If I use #pragma ... before the loop, the cpu usage sticks 100% for about 350 s. which is more than the time taken to run program sequentially.

I would appreciate if any one could help me on the issue.

Comment: How big is `vec1._rows`?

Comment: `r` in `for` loop should be defined before `for` itself. Like this: `int r; #pragma.... for(r = 1...)`

Comment: Try to work out the parallel region further outwards. If you are calling the functions many times, you are paying as well for the initialization each time you call it

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Um, no, for a parallel for putting the loop variable outside the loop means it's 'last' value has to be preserved by omp. This is an extra overhead and will slow it down. (a little).

Comment: @javad, You're on Windows right? Taskman on Windows says 25% for one core on a 4 core machine. Really dumb question here ... you are using a multi-core machine aren't you ?

Comment: @user3710044: take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Clauses_in_work-sharing_constructs_.28in_C.2FC.2B.2B.29 at the `for` example. It says: "Notice how the iteration counters j and k have to be made private" If you want to mark something as `public` or `private` it must already exist (so must be visible before `#pragma`)

Comment: @MichałWalenciak, true, but then a loop variable defined within the loop is by definition private.

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode? Have you enabled OpenMP in MSVC?

Answer (score 1):

This can go wrong in a number of ways:

1. without knowing the type of `result`, it's possible that barriers have to be built in to avoid a race condition when modifying it -- you could avoid that by having parallel result vectors that you merge afterwards.
2. copy overhead for the `vec1` and `vec2` vectors might be bigger than performance reward.

all in all, this is a question about parallelizable vector types -- refer to your openMP documentation of choice to learn more about parallely accessible types.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I just looked it up and from the OMP specification ...

• A throw executed inside a loop region must cause execution to resume within the same iteration of the loop region, and the same thread that threw the exception must catch it.

I knew I didn't like the look of the exception.

OpenMP API V4.0 page 59.